# iOS swift programatically disable wifi auto join option

Tags: ios, swift, nehotspothelper

is there possible to programatically disable wifi auto join option in iPhone?

any help will be appreciated. thanks in advance

Comment: You should have no business turning on and off with someone else's WiFi setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short Answer: No.

Longer: This would violate the general idea of a sandbox if a process within the sandbox changes the system outside.

Think the other way around: You can check the SCNetworkReachability flags about the current connection and respond within your app.